# Django manage.py commands slow; zlib issue suspected

Tags: python, django, homebrew, zlib

When developing Django apps on my local machine (a OSX 10.8 MacBook), running Django commands (through the manage.py interface) is extremely slow, much slower than on an identical laptop at work. At work, running `python manage.py runserver` is essentially instant, but on this machine running even `python manage.py --help` takes between 15 and 30 seconds to complete.

I suspect this to be an issue with my mac's installed zlib module, because of the following: running Python in verbose mode shows the message

```
# zipimport: zlib available
```

being printed close to a thousand times before any `manage.py` command will complete. The time which it takes all of these messages to be printed is roughly equal to the time difference in running `manage.py` commands on my local and work computers.

I'm thinking I have some kind of circular import, but I'm not really sure what direction to go in solving it.

The above problem surfaces both when zlib is installed through Homebrew, and when only the system default module is in  place.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/bjacobel/6201522) of the typical output from running `python -v manage.py --help` on my machine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you tell us where in your packages this zlib module is imported ? I guess you may import it into a file like settings.py or manage.py and maybe then he's imported many times...

Comment: For comparison, the same command on mine looks like this: https://gist.github.com/whatisjasongoldstein/9b6a0a4ea046241e7eb8, and has minimal message of zlib.

Comment: Zlib is not imported anywhere in any of the projects that have been experiencing this problem, but I did find an import of it in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py`?

Comment: I thought that `Zlib` was a critical part of the whole Python runtime, since it is used to unpack `.egg` files (which are essentially Zip archives containing Python files)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've resolved the issue, or at least hidden its effects. I had the following line in my `.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

which was causing all kinds of weird things to happen, including Python using copies of modules outside of my virtual environments instead of copies inside the environment. I still suspect that zlib is broken (and maybe larger parts of my OSX system Python installation) but removing this line from my `.bashrc` solved the `manage.py` issue, at least.